# How do I run an apex class from the Force IDE like it would run as a CronTrigger?

Tags: apex, ide

I have an Apex class which implements the Schedulable interface. I have scheduled this class to run once a day in my developer sandbox, but I haven't been sure it's running.

I installed the Force.com IDE, and heard that I can run this class from the IDE manually. I haven't found anything in the Force IDE docs that points how to do this. Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

If you already have scheduled a class you can verify it by going to Setup--> Administration Setup --> monitoring --> scheduled jobs and see if the job exists and when the next run is scheduled at.

You can set up a job to be scheduled from your developer console and do not need eclipse for this. Open your Dev console (setup --> developer console)  and paste the schedule script you have and hit execute,this should show you a success/ failure (if the job you are trying to schedule already exists with the same name).

You can also do this from eclipse,but using eclipse for this is not required.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to launch your scheduled process from Eclipse, you can do it in the Execute Anonymous window. Enter something like the following and then click the Execute Anonymous button:

```
System.schedule('Unique Schedule Name', '0 0 1 * * ?', new ScheduleClass());
```

This can be helpful when you want to run a schedule every hour of every day, instead of the maximum daily recurrence allowed through the standard interface. The following will run on the hour:

```
System.schedule('Schedule Name', '0 0 0-23 * * ?', new ScheduleClass());
```

Comment: Thanks for the response - is there any way to run it on demand? The Salesforce support rep I talked to said that was possible from the Force IDE.

Comment: That's exactly what this is - on demand. This isn't code sitting in a class somewhere. Just paste in the Execute Anonymous window and executed on demand. You can execute DML in this way as well which will commit data to your org: insert new Contact(LastName='TEST'); etc.

Comment: I got it running with this invocation:                          MyClass rm = new MyClass();
rm.execute(null);